# Is お父さん appropriate for formal writing?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, synonyms

As I understand it お父さん is the usual way to refer to someone else's father in everyday speech.

What about when you are writing a formal discussion (for an academic audience) of an interview you had with someone? Is 父 or 父親 better for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the exact opposite, when writing especially for an academic audience you should minimize the amount of 敬語 as there specific styling for just that use case (である/だ vs. です)

according to a tertiary search on Google, it seems just using 父 and 母 is best.

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1244256012

Comment: Thanks for finally providing an answer that doesn't sound bizarre. guess I'll just use 知恵袋 from now on

Answer (score 1):

I would take no risk, and go with お父様.

In my understanding, 父親 is more like the generic word for father. From http://jisho.org:

> Father
> A father (or dad) is defined as a male parent or Individual progenitor of human offspring.